# Cost/ License of Ubuntu Machine

Tags: license

I want to use Ubuntu based computer (2 machines) in organization 
1) to run some learning initiative
2) Some production small projects.

Please let me know if there is any licensing fee if I don't expect any support (from community or professionals) in both these situations.
Regards,
Sumit

Answer (score 1):

You only need to pay for the Hardware.

Ubuntu and all its bundled softwares is completely [free to use](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/our-philosophy). Support for official releases is free too and almost all the support is provided by the community at

1. [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org)
2. [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com)